# What will happen if you don't await a async function?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

If I don't use `await` to call the async function, I will get back a coroutine. In that case, what will happen for the coroutine? Do I have to manually execute the coroutine? Or this coroutine will continue to run itself in the background?

Using `await`

```
async def work():
    result = await stuff()
```

Without `await`

```
async def work():
     result = stuff()
```

Comment: It will get stuck. It's a good idea to always `await f()` instead of just `f()`.

Comment: Did you try it? The exception you get is informative. It will tell you that `stuff` is never executed.

Comment: A very tricky question. In JS if you dont await for async functions it will be scheduled anyway.

Comment: @askaroni Please fact-check your comment again. Apparently your "It will get stuck" comment shows up in my Google Search result, but I know better that it shouldn't be true.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco why would this be a very tricky question? The python docs explain exactly what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the official docs:

> Note that simply calling a coroutine will not schedule it to be executed:

That means you did not call your function actually so there no one waiting for anything and nothing to be waiting for if you did not place `await` before your function call.

You could instead schedule a task for it or many tasks using `asyncio`:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t1 = loop.create_task(stuff())
    t2 = loop.create_task(stuff())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

To find more about this, I would recommend reading
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Answer (score 0):

In *Python* it would **ignore the call** and print out the issue.

Different from the expected if you have a JavaScript background where the code is executed even if there is not an await.

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')


asyncio.run(main())
```

> Ignored

```bash
Hello ...
 World!
/Users/jtovar/PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/async_question.py:6: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
  asyncio.sleep(1)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')


asyncio.run(main())
```

> it works!

```bash
Hello ...
 World!
```

> it works! without await

```js
async function sleep() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function main() {
  console.log('Hello ...');
  sleep();
  console.log('... World!');
}

main();
```

```bash
Hello ...
 World!
```